# How to make the changes made by admin appear and on member pages using ASP..NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've created a basic member-role web aapplication using ASP.NET Web form (C#). This is a proto-type for project management website but just a very tiny one, so far there are two role users. Admin and students, where admin will be only one, while students can be many, upto twenty.

1. I'm looking for a technique, that will allow me to create a web page, through which I can view list of projects available for students to work with and select a student from drop-down list. The selection must notify the particular student user, once he logs on in red text, that should be only once, this notification should never appear again.
2. If I create a list of other users, or create a list of projects, it must be displayed on the student's page as well. The newly created lists or upadted version of list must take effedt on all user pages.

Comment: SignalR can be a possible solution, however asking for technical recommendations doesn't really fit here.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla Thanks for your help, although you helped me to learn something new but it didn't really help me even close to my question